# XSL-FO splitting footnotes across pages?

Tags: xsl-fo

I need to produce an invoice-like document using XSL-FO. On the first page of the document, I want to display a simple and short summary table, after which I should display footnotes. If the footnotes could not all be displayed on the first page (which will happen), I want the footnotes to continue displaying on the next pages.

Problem is, on the next pages, there is detailed information about the content of the first page, and I cannot manually break after a specific footnote, because all my content is auto-generated.

Any way to achieve that?

[Edit:] So I found out that I could use footnote elements exactly for footnotes, but I shouldn't use it for stuff that spans across multiple pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOP crashes if you have more footnotes than you can fit on a page.

The simple solution to my problem is to make sure I always have enough space to fit footnotes through, by adding an extra blank page as a safety so my footnotes can flow freely.

I'm pretty sure there's a more elegant solution out there, but for my needs it's simpler to add a page there and delete it manually if I need to later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AH Formatter, then you can use `axf:footnote-max-height` to specify the maximum height to allow the footnotes.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#axf.footnote-max-height and "A footnote breaking across multiple pages (axf:footnote-max-height)" in https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/.